# Python: How to write to csv a dict of list "in line"?

Tags: python, csv

I wish to write my dict of list to a csv file, I need to sort my row by key name:

```
import csv

dict_of_list = {"key1": [1,2,3], "key2": [4,5,6], "key3": [7,8,9]}

#line bugged corrected bellow:
# keys = sorted(dict_of_list.keys())
writer.writerows(sorted([k, *vs] for k, vs in dict_of_list.items()))


with open("P:/Code/Python/CSV/dict_of_list.csv", "w") as tmp:
    writer = csv.writer(tmp)
    writer.writerows(zip(dict_of_list.items()))
```

I need the csv file to be ordered like:

```
key1, 1, 2, 3
key2, 4, 5, 6
key3, 7, 8, 9
```

Actualy my output csv is:

```
"('key1', [1, 2, 3])"
"('key2', [4, 5, 6])"
"('key3', [7, 8, 9])"
```

I've tried other code but I could only put the keys in the header or no keys at all.

I would be grateful if someone could give me a push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are writing the tuples, do this instead:

```
import csv

dict_of_list = {"key2": [4, 5, 6], "key3": [7, 8, 9], "key1": [1, 2, 3], }

with open("output.csv", "w") as tmp:
    writer = csv.writer(tmp)
    writer.writerows([k, *vs] for k, vs in sorted(dict_of_list.items()))
```

**Output**

```
key1,1,2,3
key2,4,5,6
key3,7,8,9
```

The expression:

```
[k, *vs] for k, vs in dict_of_list.items()
```

creates a list where the first element is the key and the rest of the elements are the values. 
**Update**
The `*vs` *unpacks* the elements of the list, see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). If you want the elements sorted by key, do this, as suggested by @tdelaney:

```
writer.writerows(sorted([k, *vs] for k, vs in dict_of_list.items()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's work perfectly. Could you explain me the part: "  [k, *vs] for k, vs  " , I don't understand the *vs . Or a link about the  * usage.

Comment: `keys = sorted(dict_of_list.keys())` doesn't sort the dict. How about `writer.writerows([k, *vs] for k, vs in sorted(dict_of_list.items()))` ?

Comment: @tdelaney The second option does sort the dictionary

Comment: But the first example does not sort the dictionary. May I suggest removing the current sort line and adding to the writerows?

Comment: @tdelaney Feel free to edit the question. Which line are you referring?

Comment: I'm not sure I should correct my code in my question post because other people won't understand why I was asking it (or the really nice anwers I get with).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of managing the writing of the file all by yourself you could use the `pandas` library instead.

For that you simply create a pandas DataFrame (like a table) from your dictionary with the orientation set to `orient=index`, because your dictionary keys should serve as the rows of your table.
Then you simply use the DataFrame method `to_csv` to write your csv file. 
You can use the `header=False` parameter when you do not want a header.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_of_list, orient="index").sort_index()
df.to_csv("test.csv", sep=";", header=False)
```

Comment: I know that pandas is really powefull. At the moment, I'll stick with the basics with a few librairies. I'll try to get solid basics. Anyway, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be solved using pandas's method to_csv()

```
import pandas
dict_of_list = {"key1": [1,2,3], "key2": [4,5,6], "key3": [7,8,9]}

df = pandas.DataFrame(dict_of_list)
df.T.sort_index().to_csv("test.csv",sep=";",header=False)
```